# iOS web app, Fullscreen?

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

Is there any way to determine whether you're in Safari fullscreen mode when you're using the meta tag `apple-mobile-web-app-capable`?

Comment: <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

Comment: Yes, I think it was with javascript, i'll search it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this one

```
window.navigator.standalone
```

It is `true` in full screen